# How to style dropdown arrow button when its in an input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working with an input element and not a select element. With the input element I am using `<datalist>` tag to have it act as a dropdown menu. The dropdown arrow is not looking the way it should, but a lot of the guides out there show how to style a dropdown arrow for a `<select>` element which works, but those solutions do not seem to work when it is a dropdown arrow using `<datalist>` tag in an `<input>` element.

```css
.input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60px;
  width: 424px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

datalist #questions {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 9.17px;
  width: 13.5px;
  border: 0.5px solid #CCCCCC;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<label class="control-label">Please select a question</label>
<input class="input flex-item" list="questions" />
<datalist id="questions">
  <option value="How old are you?">
  <option value="Where do you live?">
  <option value="Are you married?">
  <option value="Do you have any children?">
</datalist>
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't. The longer answer is that each browser implements its own proprietary styling properties that allows for some customization of the components of native browser elements, but they do not provide a consistent look across all clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, you can't, but you could try this:

```
<div>
  <input class="input flex-item" list="questions" />
  <datalist id="questions">
    <option value="How old are you?">
    <option value="Where do you live?">
    <option value="Are you married?">
    <option value="Do you have any children?">
  </datalist>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

```
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 2
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

This code working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pjta9e?file=style.css

Comment: I like this idea but the default -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator is still showing in Chrome so we see two arrows when hover/focus input.